# how I can create a table and a trigger in mysql with springframework and maven?

Tags: mysql, maven

I am continuing the development of an android app that works against a server using maven, springframework and server database is MySQL.

need 2 very specific things:

1. I want to create a table
2. I want to create a trigger

But I want to create from springframework and maven and I could not find a way to do it.

Since it is a project among several people I want to be as automatic as possible to keep things simple.

I want to start when the server maven can create the table and the trigger if there are not exist.

It will be done?

I would like a simple example or a site I can visit and give me at least the concept of how.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a tool which builds your application. It's not available when the application runs. Therefore, it's often not the best choice to create database tables, etc.

A better approach is to locate the place where Spring's `ApplicationContext` is created and add code there that examines the database, finds out which tables already exist and create those which don't.

Later, you can extend the code to migrate data when your data model changes.

To execute SQL, check the [Spring JDBC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) and especially `JdbcTemplate`.